# Laravel controller for a commenting system

Tags: object-oriented, mvc, ajax, php5, laravel

Can someone review my Controller? I should follow these guidelines:

> Code should be written with MVC pattern and to use OOP.

The code now works fine, but I need to improve it. Also, should I use more Ajax Model?

This code is used to receive data from a jQuery script and send it back. Almost every method does the same.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Cookie;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class AjaxController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */


    public function index()
    {

               if(Input::get('task') && Input::get('task') == 'comment_insert'){
                $userID = Input::get('userID');
                $comment = nl2br(Input::get('comment'));
                $name = Input::get('name');
                $date = Input::get('date');

                if(Input::get('picture')){
                     $img = Input::get('picture');
                }else{
                     $img = 'http://thecontentwrangler.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/User.png';
                }

                    $qv = DB::table('comments')
                        ->insert(array(
                            'name'   => $name,
                            'comment' => $comment,
                            'current_date' => $date,
                            'avatar'  => $img
                        ));

            $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

                if($qv){
                $out = array('date' => $date,
                            'userID' => $userID,
                             'comment' => $comment,
                            'comment_id' => $id,
                            'userName' => $name,
                            'photo_img' => $img);

                return Response::make(json_encode($out));
            }
            }

        }
        public function reply()
    {
              if(Input::get('task') && Input::get('task') == 'reply_insert'){
                $commentID = Input::get('commentID');
                $comment = nl2br(Input::get('comment'));
                $name = Input::get('name');
                $date = Input::get('date');
                $level = Input::get('levelBR');
                $order= Input::get('order');
                $id_rep = Input::get('id_rep');
                $nametorep = Input::get('nametorep');
                $level += 1;
                    if(Input::get('picture')){
                         $img = Input::get('picture');
                    }else{
                         $img = 'http://thecontentwrangler.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/User.png';
                    }
                    if($order == 'NULL'){
                        $order = NULL;
                    }
                    $qv = DB::table('replays')
                          ->insert(array(
                              'name'   => $name,
                              'comment' => $comment,
                              'comment_integer' => $commentID,
                              'level'   => $level,
                              'nametorep' => $nametorep,
                              'current_date' => $date,
                              'order' => $order,
                              'avatar' => $img
                          ));

                    $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

                    $out = array(
                                'date' => $date,
                                'order' => $order,
                                'nametorep' => $nametorep,
                                'commentID' => $commentID,
                                'comment' => $comment,
                                'replyID' => $id,
                                'name'    => $name,
                                'levelBR' => $level,
                                'photo_img' => $img
                    );

                    return Response::make(json_encode($out));

            }

        }


        public function checkHash($table,$colCol,$colRep,$comment,$reply){
                if($reply == 'NULL'){
                  $hashs = DB::select("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $colRep IS NULL && $colCol =?", array($comment));

                }else{
                   $hashs = DB::select("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $colRep = ? && $colCol =?", array($reply,$comment ));
                }

                foreach ($hashs as $h){
                    if(Cookie::get($h->hash)){
                        return true;
                    }
                 }

      }

        public static function make($string,$salt=''){
                return hash('sha256',$string . $salt);
        }

        public static function unique(){
                return self::make(uniqid());
        }

        public function upVote(){
          if(Input::get('task') && Input::get('task') == true){
              $reply = Input::get('reply');
              $comment = Input::get('comment');
              $vote  = Input::get('vote');
              $voteCom  = Input::get('voteCom');
              intval($vote);
              intval($voteCom);
                if (self::checkHash('hashs','comment_integer','reply_integer',$comment,$reply)) {
                    $out1= array('voted' => 'You have already voted.');
                     return json_encode($out1);
                 }  else {
                    $hash = self::unique();
                    $cookie = Cookie::forever($hash, 7);

                        if($reply == 'NULL'){
                            $reply = NULL;
                            DB::table('comments')->where(array('id' => $comment ))->increment('vote_up', 1);

                        }else{
                            DB::table('replays')->where(array('id' => $reply,'comment_integer' => $comment ))->increment('vote_up', 1);
                        }

                  DB::table('hashs')->insert(array('comment_integer' => $comment, 'reply_integer' => $reply,'hash' => $hash)); 
                  $vote = $vote + 1;
                  $voteCom = $voteCom +1;
                  $out = array('vote' => $vote,'voteCom' => $voteCom);

                 return Response::make(json_encode($out))-> withCookie($cookie);

            }

          }

          }




          public function downVote(){
          if(Input::get('task')){

              $reply = Input::get('reply');
              $comment = Input::get('comment');
              $vote  = Input::get('vote');
              $voteCom  = Input::get('voteCom');
              intval($vote);
              intval($voteCom);
                    if (self::checkHash('hashs','comment_integer','reply_integer',$comment,$reply)) {
                        $out1= array('voted' => 'You have already voted.');
                        return json_encode($out1);
                     }  else {

               $hash = self::unique();
               $cookie = Cookie::forever($hash, 7);

                    if($reply == 'NULL'){
                        $reply = NULL;
                        DB::table('comments')->where(array('id' => $comment ))->increment('vote_down', 1);

                    }else{
                        DB::table('replays')->where(array('id' => $reply,'comment_integer' => $comment ))->increment('vote_down', 1);
                    }
                  DB::table('hashs')->insert(array('comment_integer' => $comment, 'reply_integer' => $reply,'hash' => $hash)); 
                  $vote = $vote + 1;
                  $voteCom = $voteCom +1;
                  $out = array('vote' => $vote,'voteCom' => $voteCom);

                     return Response::make(json_encode($out))-> withCookie($cookie);

            }

          }

          }


          public function report(){
              if(Input::get('task')){
                 $commentID = Input::get('comment');
                 $replyID =Input::get('reply');

                        if(self::checkHash('hashreport','comment_report_id','reply_report_id',$commentID,$replyID)){
                            $out1= array('reported' => 'Comment already reported.');
                            return json_encode($out1);
                        }  else {
                      $hash = self::unique();
                      $cookie = Cookie::forever($hash, 7);

                      if($replyID == 'NULL'){
                          $replyID = NULL;
                          DB::table('comments')->where(array('id' => $commentID ))->increment('report', 1);

                      }else{
                          DB::table('replays')->where(array('id' => $replyID,'comment_integer' => $commentID ))->increment('report', 1);
                      }

                         DB::table('hashreport')->insert(array('comment_report_id' => $commentID, 'reply_report_id' => $replyID,'hash' => $hash)); 

                         $out = array('report' => 'This comment is reported. Thanks!');

                        return Response::make(json_encode($out))-> withCookie($cookie);
                  }


              }
          }

          private function getComments($order){
             $comments = DB::select("SELECT avatar,name, vote_up,vote_down,report,id,comment,`current_date`,comment_integer,level FROM ( SELECT avatar,name, vote_up,vote_down,report,id,comment,`current_date`,comment_integer,level  FROM comments UNION ALL SELECT avatar,name, vote_up,vote_down,report,id,comment,`current_date`,comment_integer,level  FROM replays ) T ORDER BY $order DESC");

             return $comments;
          }

          public function bylikes(){
              //SELECT name, vote_up FROM ( SELECT name, vote_up FROM comments UNION ALL SELECT name, vote_up FROM replays ) T ORDER BY vote_up DESC
                if(Input::get('task')){
                 return json_encode(self::getComments('vote_up'));
                }

          }

          public function bydiss(){
              //SELECT name, vote_up FROM ( SELECT avatar,name, vote_up FROM comments UNION ALL SELECT name, vote_up FROM replays ) T ORDER BY vote_up DESC
           if(Input::get('task')){
               return json_encode(self::getComments('vote_down'));
           }

          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all; your controller does too many things.

You may need to move your database related queries out of the controller. Repositories maybe? Also use Eloquent it is one of the most powerful way of Laravel.

methods `checkHash`, `unique`, `make` should not be in the controller.

Instead of facades you may inject `Illuminate\Http\Request` into the constructor and use request instead of input facades.

Move your business logic related functionalities into Services and inject these services into your controller. (method on constructor injection)

Instead of `Response::make(json_encode($abc))` you may use `response()->json($abc)`

You need to follow a naming convention for your controller methods, variables and functions.

You need to indent your code.